# find $u,v\in \mathbb Z$ such that $231u+45v=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

I have to find $u,v\in \mathbb Z$ such that $231u+45v=1$. By Euclide algorithm, 
\begin{align*}
231&=5\cdot 45+6\\
45&=6\cdot 7+3\\
7&=3\cdot 2+1
\end{align*}
The first equation gives $$6=231-5\cdot 45.$$
We put this in the second equation, and we get
$$45=(231-5\cdot 45)\cdot 7+3\implies 3=36\cdot 45-7\cdot 231.$$
Now I replace $3$ in the last equation, and obtain
$$7=2\cdot (36\cdot 45-7\cdot 231)+1\implies 7-72\cdot 45+14\cdot 231=1,$$

but the 7 disturbs me, did I do my algorithm wrong ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde : What are you saying ? I have never duplicated anything ! I'm just looking what wrong in my computation.

Comment: There are no integer solutions to $231u+45v=1$, because $3\mid 231u$ and $3\mid 45v$, but $3\nmid 1$.

Comment: @MathBeginner Oh, I see. There is a typo in the question. We have $gcd(231,46)=1$. In your case it would be impossible with $45$, because $gcd(231,45)=3$. The extended Euclidean algorithm is usually used, so that I mean by duplicate. The question has been answered already at MSE (well, without typo, I mean).

Comment: In the algorithm, write $45 = 7 \cdot 6 + 3$ instead of $45 = 6 \cdot 7 + 3$. (The first line says that $\gcd(231,45) = \gcd(45,6)$, so you need to continue with $45$ and $6$ instead of with $45$ and $7$). Then, continue with $6 = \dots$. Still, there is no integer solution to $231 u + 45 v = 1$ because, as you will see, $\gcd(231,45) = 3$, but this explains why you seem to come up with a $\gcd$ of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

#### Hint:

$$\gcd(231;45)=3$$

Then $$3|231u+45v$$

Comment: It's exactly what I did. Then I get $7-2\cdot (45-7\cdot (231-5\cdot 45))$ and the $7$ is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Answer

$$\gcd(231;45)=3$$

Then $$3|231u+45v$$

BUT $$3\nmid1$$

So No integer solutions

Comment: ok, my error. Sorry and thank you

Comment: Why downvote? Any problem to be fixed??

Answer (score 1):

You did not apply the Euclidean algorithm correctly.

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ with $a \geq b$.  Then we apply the Euclidean algorithm as follows.  Apply the Division Algorithm to $a$ and $b$ to obtain
$$a = q_1b + r_1, 0 \leq r_1 < b$$
If $r_1 = 0$, then $\gcd(a, b) = b$.  Otherwise, divide $b$ by $r_1$ to obtain 
$$b = q_2r_1 + r_2, 0 \leq r_2 < r_1$$
If $r_2 = 0$, then the process stops and $\gcd(a, b) = r_1$.  Otherwise, the process continues until some zero remainder appears, at, say, the stage when $r_{n - 1}$ is divided by $r_n$.  Then
\begin{align*}
a & = q_1b + r_1, && \text{$0 < r_1 < b$}\\
b & = q_2r_1 + r_2, &&  \text{$0 < r_2 < r_1$}\\
r_1 & = q_3r_2 + r_3, && \text{$0 < r_3 < r_2$}\\
& \quad \vdots\\
r_{n - 2} & = q_nr_{n - 1} + r_n, && \text{$0 < r_n < r_{n - 1}$}\\
r_{n - 1} & = q_{n + 1}r_n + 0
\end{align*}
where the last non-zero remainder $r_n = \gcd(a, b)$.

When you applied the Euclidean algorithm, you should have obtained
\begin{align*}
231 & = 5 \cdot 45 + 6\\
45 & = 7 \cdot 6 + 3\\
6 & = 2 \cdot 3 + 0
\end{align*}
You made your mistake in the third line, where you used $q_1 = 7$ instead of $r_1 = 6$.

Since the last non-zero remainder is $3$, $\gcd(231, 45) = 3$.  As others have pointed out, the left side of the equation $231x + 45y = 1$ is divisible by $3$, while $1$ is not divisible by $3$.  Hence, the equation has no solutions in the integers.

Answer (score 0):

**Bezout’s Lemma or the Linear Diophantine Equation Theorem**

For all $a, b\in Z$, not both zero, there exists, $x, y\in Z$
such that $ax+by=c$ if and only if $\gcd(a, b)$ divides $c\,$, $$\gcd(231, 45)=3 $$

Answer (score -1):

Let's calculate the greatest common divisor:
$\left( \begin{array}{lcr}
231 & 1 & 0 \\
45  & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \rightarrow \left( \begin{array}{lcr}
6 & 1 & -5 \\
45  & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \rightarrow \left( \begin{array}{lcr}
6 & 1 & -5 \\
3  & -7 & 36 \\
\end{array}
\right) \rightarrow \left( \begin{array}{lcr}
0 & 15 & -77 \\
3  & -7 & 36 \\
\end{array}
\right) \rightarrow$
Then the greatest common divisor is 3 and its beonzout equation  $3=(231)(-7)+(45)(36)$, then $d=g.c.d(231,45)=3\rightarrow d|(231x+45y)$, which it is imposible, 3 does not divide to 1, then does not exist $u\ and\  v$